# How to install amdgpu -pro in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: amd-graphics

I have amd radeon hd 5450 and i am trying to install amdgpu . I download a 80mb file and extracted it . In amd support page it tells to  run the included script (amdgpu-pro-install) to install the graphics stack .
1st question : how to run the script

i did some research and found that draging the amdgpu-pro-install to terminal will do it but at the end it shows

E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro

iam running 32bit operating system and have 2gb of ram

Comment: Go to the folder the script is in in the terminal and type `sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install`.

Comment: Note: On AMD support page they mention `./amdgpu-pro-install –y`. But on the newest download (v17) I got an error adding '-y'. Do not add it if you get error. Anyway, the answer you need is on AMD site. To run: Open terminal/shell/console: `sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install`  Wait. When done, reboot. Add 'video' to user groups/logout/login. Done.

Comment: @bshea That's because those instructions contain a subtle typo if you are copy/pasting.  That `–y` should be `-y`.

Answer (score 8):

To install amdgpu-pro, open a terminal and run the following commands one at a time

```
mkdir /tmp
cd tmp
wget --referer=http://support.amd.com  https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ubuntu/amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz
​tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz
cd amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261
amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install
```

Ensure that your user account is a member of the "video" group prior to using the vulkan driver. You can find which groups you are a member of with the following command:

```
groups
```

If not add yourself

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
```

That should be it, to check it installed

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
```

To remove it

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

Comment: `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME`does not add me to the video group no matter how much I run it

Comment: @Tooniis even after logging out and back in?

Comment: You simply copied AMD page http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

Comment: @bshea Of course, where else do you think the information for installing AMD drivers come from, if not AMD?

Comment: The wget referrer is important, without it the site stopped me from download the drivers from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The amdgpu driver does not support the hd5450.

You should be using the radeon-based drivers that are included in the distro install image.

Comment: Can you provide instructions for using the drivers you recommend?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix They come pre-installed with all Ubuntu installations.

Comment: I meant `modprobe`, etc.

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct answer. Supported cards are listed in the driver release notes, for example: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx.